# CRA_Xcrms_ProcessRequest - what does it mean? or what process is this?

Tags: database

the Public Service Development Agency is going to give me access to database (Information about an individual in an electronic database). They contacted me and said that in the near future, they will provide me with the data needed for testing, said that I will receive data via CRA_Xcrms_ProcessRequest.

Wonder what is CRA_Xcrms_ProcessRequest, or what does it mean?
Is that some kind of SQL thing or other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From looking around, the only reference I can find to this is used as a xml namespace (xmlns). Most likely they keep data in a particular format and identify that format by using xml namespaces, but it would be impossible to say without working with them in particular, as anyone can declare an [xmlns](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/srivastava-namespaces.html)